# Unable to resolve NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I was implementing this method, and I was facing a Nullpointer exception on the line (Mentioned by a comment) I haven't been able to figure out why it was happening, would appreciate if someone could point out where I am going wrong

```
public Code visitCallNode(StatementNode.CallNode node) {
        beginGen("Call");
        SymEntry.ProcedureEntry proc = node.getEntry();
        Code code = new Code();
        List<ExpNode> aps = node.getActualParams();
        Type.ProcedureType pt = proc.getType();
        List<SymEntry.ParamEntry> fps = pt.getFormalParams();

        int offset = 1-(fps.size());
        int a=0;
        int r=0;

        for (SymEntry.ParamEntry temp:fps) {
            String id = temp.getIdent();
            a++;
            for (ExpNode temp1 : aps) { //THIS IS THE LINE THROWING THE EXCEPTION
                ActualParamNode apn = (ActualParamNode) temp1;
                if (((ActualParamNode) temp1).getId().equals(id)) {
                    code.append(apn.genCode(this));
                    if (apn.getCondition() instanceof ExpNode.VariableNode) {
                        r++;
                    }
                    a++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (a > 0) {
                code.append(temp.getDefaultExp().genCode(this));
                if (temp.getDefaultExp() instanceof ExpNode.VariableNode) {
                    r++;
                }
            }

            if (r == 0) {
                if(temp.isRef()){
                    code.generateOp(Operation.TO_GLOBAL);
                } else {
                    code.generateOp(Operation.LOAD_ABS);
                }
            }
            offset++;
            temp.setOffset(offset);
        }
        code.genCall(staticLevel - proc.getLevel(), proc);
        endGen("Call");
        return code;
    }
```

Comment: That means `aps` is `null`, which means `node.getActualParams()` is `null`. 
Since we don't see what `node` is and where it comes from, there's no much more we can say to help. You may still secure your code by throwing an exception to the caller if they send a `node` which contains a `null` list of actual parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the list from "node.getActualParams()" actually exists,(Something like printing the size of the node).